# Check for Null values without IF statements

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, if-statement, nullpointerexception

I have the following method that gets multiple optional values as parameters.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/search", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE , MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<String> getCategoriesByExample(
        @RequestParam(required = false) String id,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String name,
...
){
```

The problem is, since all the parameters are optional, when I assign them in a object I need to check all of them for nullability in such a way that multiple *IF's* are necessary. If I don't, the  program throws an error for assigning the variable a null value.

```
Category cat = new Category();
    
    if (id!=null) 
        cat.setId(UUID.fromString(id));
    
    if (name!=null) 
        cat.setName(name);
...
```

So is there a way for me to  to check all of then without using the *if* statement?

Comment: You can bind directly Category in the params and spring will do the rest for you

Comment: @b.GHILAS This doesn't work for me, because I need to pass the values separately.

Comment: What do you mean pass the values separately ?

Comment: @b.GHILAS, I mean that I cannot alter the method's declaration.